# Lighttpd proxy module - use with hostname

Tags: proxy, lighttpd, hostname

I have to proxy a site which is hosted on an external webspace through my lighty on example.org. 
My config so far:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/webmail" {
    proxy.server =  ("/webmail/" => (
        # this entry should link to example2.org
        ("host" => "1.2.3.4", "port" => 80)
    ))
}
```

The webspace provider has configured my domain as vhost. So if i access http://1.2.3.4/webmail/ lighttpd will only deliver the main site of the
    webspace provider which says "Site example.org was not found on our server."

Any suggestions how i have to configure lighty to proxy sites that are only hosted as vhost (and do not have an ip on their own)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be fixed with *mod_setenv*:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/webmail" {
    # add host header
    setenv.add-request-header ( "Host" => "example2.org" )

    proxy.server =  ("/webmail/" => (
        # this entry should link to example2.org
        ("host" => "1.2.3.4", "port" => 80)
    ))
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work. add-request-header just ADDs a header, so the request will contain "example.org, example2.org" as host header. There's an patch that enables set-request-header. That's not an option, I want to continue using the maintainers lighty version. Otherwise I'll have to patch my build by hand every time a security update gets released.

Comment: Which version of Lighty do you use?

Comment: I'am using Version 1.4.29

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your hosting provider to support the `X-Forwarded-Host` header. Maybe it already works, try it. This can be readily added with built-in lighttpd capabilities.

```
proxy.forwarded = ( "host" => 1 )
```

enables it in your proxying server.